# Failed to create a new AVD?

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

[image]

As shown in the above image, all the necessary information have been filled but however the "OK" button is still disabled for me to proceed? May I know which part is going wrong?

Comment: There is no a system image for API 20 in your AVD (CPU/ABI). You need to download and install one in Android SDK Manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dropdown box besides CPU/ABI shows `No system images installed for this target` and is disabled. That's why the Ok button is also disabled. Either install the system image of the target you've selected (in your case, `Android 4.4W - API Level 20`) via the Android SDK Manager, or choose another target with a system image installed.

Comment: At my SDK Manager, it has two **System Image** available, may I know which one should I install? 
(Android Wear ARM EABI v7a System Image & Android Wear Intel x86 Atom System Image)

Comment: The `ARM EABI v7a System Image` is the standard one to go. The `Intel x86 Atom System Image` may have better performance, but it may also be less stable than the ARM Image.